# ImportError: cannot import name SSLError

Tags: python, importerror

I need the SSLError utility function but ...

```
from requests.exceptions import SSLError
```

and I get ImportError: cannot import name SSLError :(

PS: I have installed python-requests in Ubuntu using the python-requests package

Comment: have you tried `from requests import exceptions`?

Comment: Is SSLError not just in 'ssl'?

Comment: @Max: no, not with the `requests` package.

Comment: @Panos: What version of `requests` is this? What is the value of `requests.__version__`? If you import `requests.exceptions`, what is the value of `request.exceptions.__file__`?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.3

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.3.  However, `from requests import exceptions` works without problem. My professor told me to use SSLError, I don't know if ssl and SSLError are similar. Hm ?
@MartijnPieters : the requests.__version__ is 0.8.2  and the request.exceptions.__file__ is /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/exceptions.pyc

Comment: @PanosGeorgiadis: your `requests` version is too old; you'll have to upgrade it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `requests` library version is too old. The `SSLError` exception was not added to `requests.exceptions` until version 0.8.8, in [revision 9a1a413](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/commit/9a1a4136ac69cce55d8d5f27a0ab1caadb0a6e90).